# How to join/decline/maybe event with facebook API in iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to perform join/decline or maybe operation on Facebook event in my application.

How to set operation permision for event in ios application in Facebook API?

Please provide solution, which permission is required for event action in Facebook graph API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for attending event you have to use below code or for more details go through [Facebook documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/)

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{event-id}/attending"
                         parameters:nil
                         HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(
                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                      id result,
                      NSError *error
                  ) {
                      /* handle the result */
                  }];
```